# One obvservablelist for all visualisations in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

Is there anyway to use one ObservableList for all visualisation types in JavaFX? For example, I have a PieChart with a PieChart.Data observable list, how can I use the data in the observablelist in a BarChart?

*EDIT*

Okay, since it's not possible, let me rephrase.

My application gets data from SQL, views it in a TableView, then visualizes the data in the TableView with a PieChart. How can I get both for example PieChart and BarChart from the TableView?

Here's my code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

String url = "just my db url"; 
private ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
static ObservableList<PieChart.Data> dataList
        = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private Connection con;

@FXML
private Label label;
@FXML
TableView tableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> Month;
@FXML
private TableColumn<Record, String> Value;
@FXML
private PieChart pieChart;
@FXML
private BarChart barChart;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    connectToSql();
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction2(ActionEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    bindDataToPieChart();
}

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction3(ActionEvent event) throws ClassNotFoundException {

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    Month.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("Name"));
    Value.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("pieValue"));
    tableView.setItems(dataList);
}

private void bindDataToPieChart() {
    pieChart.setData(dataList);
}

private static void bindSQLdata(String title, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    String test = rs.getString("asd");
    System.out.print(test);
    Double val = rs.getDouble("val");
    dataList.add(new PieChart.Data(test, val));
}

private void connectToSql() throws SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    conn = null;

    try {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://eskhesse\\sqlexpress;dataBaseName=test;user=sa;password=1234";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    } catch (SQLException sQLException) {
    }

    if (conn != null) {
        String SQL = "SELECT [asd],[val] FROM [test].[dbo].[test]";
        ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

        while (rs.next()) {
          bindSQLdata("asd", rs);
        }

    } else {
        System.out.print("error");
    }
}

}
```

Comment: I would just make 2 lists, one for Pie and one for Bars.  The tableView can use either, just get the names right in the PropertyValueFactory.  For PieChart.Data, it's "name" and "pieValue".

Comment: Okay, because I would want the data in the PieChart and BarChart to come from the TableView, is that possible? The whole point for the user is to select which data the user wants visualized in the tableview, then choose either barchart or piechart

Comment: Then I would make the table using the whatever is easiest from the database, then when the user chooses a chart type, just make that kind of chart.  Have a method that makes a pie chart and one that makes a bar chart.

Answer (score 1):

BarChart and PieChart don't use the same type of data.  You can do it with a binding.

Even if they use the same data like LineChart and BarChart, it doesn't work great and you can't show both at the same time.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.BarChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.CategoryAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.PieChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.DoubleStringConverter;

public class ChangePie extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //this list type will work for everything except pie chart
        ObservableList<XYChart.Data<String, Double>> xyChartData
                = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                        new XYChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13d),
                        new XYChart.Data("Oranges", 25d),
                        new XYChart.Data("Plums", 10d),
                        new XYChart.Data("Pears", 22d),
                        new XYChart.Data("Apples", 30d));

        //need to make the exact type for pie chart
        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        //copy the xy data into pie chart data
        xyChartData.stream().forEach((xy) -> {
            PieChart.Data pcd = new PieChart.Data(xy.getXValue(), xy.getYValue());
            pieChartData.add(pcd);
            //and then bind the name and value to the xvalue,yvalue
            pcd.nameProperty().bind(xy.XValueProperty());
            pcd.pieValueProperty().bind(xy.YValueProperty());
        });
        final PieChart pieChart = new PieChart(pieChartData);

        //bar chart needs a category axis
        CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        xyChartData.stream().forEach((xy) -> {
            xAxis.getCategories().add(xy.getXValue());
        });
        //and the data must be added to a series
        ObservableList<XYChart.Series<String, Double>> barChartData = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new XYChart.Series<>(xyChartData));

        final BarChart barChart = new BarChart(xAxis, new NumberAxis(), barChartData);

        //table view can use the xychart data as long as we type and name it right.
        final TableView<XYChart.Data<String, Double>> tv = new TableView<>(xyChartData);
        tv.setEditable(true);

        TableColumn<XYChart.Data<String, Double>, String> tc1 = new TableColumn<>("Name");
        tc1.setPrefWidth(100);
        //the name in XYChart.Data is xValueProperty
        tc1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("xValue"));
        tc1.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        tc1.setOnEditCommit((evt) ->{
            evt.getRowValue().setXValue(evt.getNewValue());
        });

        TableColumn<XYChart.Data<String, Double>, Double> tc2 = new TableColumn<>("Data");
        tc2.setPrefWidth(100);
        tc2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("yValue"));
        tc2.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new DoubleStringConverter()));
        tc2.setOnEditCommit((evt) ->{
            evt.getRowValue().setYValue(evt.getNewValue());
        });

        tv.getColumns().addAll(tc1, tc2);
        Button btnLine = new Button("Switch");
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(tv, pieChart, barChart, btnLine);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,800,800);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        btnLine.setOnAction((evt) ->{
            for (Iterator<Node> it = root.getChildren().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                Node n = it.next();
                if(n instanceof LineChart){
                    it.remove();
                    root.getChildren().add(new BarChart(xAxis, new NumberAxis(), barChartData));
                    break;
                } else if(n instanceof BarChart){
                    it.remove();
                    root.getChildren().add(new LineChart(xAxis, new NumberAxis(), barChartData));
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wonderwing how I managed to pull this off:

First of all I have a normal ObservableList connected to a class called Record

```
static ObservableList<Record> dataen =  FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Then I have two methods, one who adds the data to a barchart, and one who adds it to a piechart.

```
private void getBarChartData(){
    for (Record record : dataen)
    {
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(record.getFieldMonth(),record.getFieldValue()));
    }
    barChart.getData().addAll(series1);

}

private void getPieChartData(){
    for(Record record : dataen)
    {
        dataList.add(new PieChart.Data(record.getFieldMonth(),record.getFieldValue()));
    }
    pieChart.setData(dataList);

}
```